# vb.net How do I parse from String to DateTime

Tags: vb.net, casting

I have a field for a `DatePicker` called `PostDateTxt` and a TextBox for a `Time` called `thetime`  on a VB.net form. I'm currently reading the values from the form, and storing them in variables where `fullPostDate` holds the String date value in the format dd/mm/yyyy, and `postTime` holds the String time value in the format hh:mm. They are being stored as Strings since that is their format in the textboxes from which I am getting their values.

When I click the 'Update' button on the form, I am updating the date & time values for the particular item in the database. The function that's called when the 'Update' button is clicked is:

```
Protected Sub UpdateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        ...
        Dim mypostdate As String = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(PostDateTxt.Text & " " & theTime.Text)
        ...
        'Split the mypostdate variable into separate String variables for date & time
        Dim postDate As DateTime = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(fullPostDate)
        ...
    ...
End Sub
```

I now want to convert these values back to a DateTime object, and am trying to parse the Strings back to a DateTime, with the line:

```
Dim postDate As DateTime = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(fullPostDate
```

However, as I step through my code, when the above line is executed, I get an `Exception User-Unhandled` message, which says:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "03/29/3019" to type 'Date' is not valid'

Why is this? How can I cast the String value to a `Date` object?

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse`? `CDate`? You can check if the string being passed is blank or a non-date using `IsDate`

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs, you can't cast a `string` as a `DateTime`. Casting works when an object is declared as one type but also implements other types (like via inheritance or interface implementation) and you refer to it by one of those other types. (Like a `string` is an `object` so you can cast a `string` as an `object`.) A `string` isn't a `DateTime` so you can cast it as one. You can only parse or convert it, creating a new `DateTime` using the months, days, year, etc. represented in the `string`.

Comment: Also, if you're using VB.NET, set `Option Strict On`. By default VB.NET has it turned off. That allows stuff like this to compile, then when it runs you get the error. It's much better to get the error in the compiler before you run the app. You'll find all sorts of places where unsafe implicit conversions are happening. It will force you to get all the types right before it even runs.

Comment: I tried `DateTime.Parse` previously, but that didn't seem to work... I have just tried `DateTime.TryParse` as you suggested, using: `If Date.TryParse(fullPostDate, postDate) Then Console.WriteLine(" Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", fullPostDate, postDate, postDate.Kind) End If`, but the `If` statement here is equating to False....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast a String object directly into a DateTime object, which is impossible to do directly as they do not share a class hierarchy that would allow them to do so.

You should try parsing the String into a DateTime object and give the parser a date format in which to process the string.

e.g.
5/7/19 in en-UK is the 5th of July 2019, in en-US it is the 7th May 2019

```
DateTime.Parse(MyString, MyCultureInfo)
```

Where your MyCultureInfo matches the format of the date string you expect to get in.
e.g.

```
MyCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US")
```

ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave that a go with: `Dim postDate As DateTime` then `DateTime.Parse(fullPostDate, postDate)`, but (having now set Option Strict on), I get a compile error on the `postDate` argument of the call to `Parse()` stating: "The value of type 'Date' cannot be converted to IFormatProvider". I'm not sure why this is?

Comment: So you are mixing up your types. The input parameters to DateTime.Parse are of types (String, IFormatProvider). You are trying to use a DateTime as an IFormatProvider and as DateTime does not implement the interface IFormatProvider then you cannot use it.
You need something like the [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) as used in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DateTime.ParseExact`. Note the space is part of the format string and capitol MM for the month. Lower case m refers to minutes. I am sure this was a typo but the year 3019 might be out of range. :-)

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dateString As String = "01/12/2019 05:22" '
    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    Debug.Print(d.ToString)
    'Prints 12/1/2019 5:22:00 AM
End Sub
```